# What should this interface contain?

Tags: interfaces, orm, abstract-class, entity

I am creating a schema for Doctrine but first I'm creating interfaces, abstract classes (models) which will be extended by the entities.

I have a **PresentationInterface** which contain getter and setters for presentation info, **ParticipantInterface** which contains the same (firstname, lastname, email).

Both have their abstract classes, **Presentation** and **Participant** which implement the getter and setters and also contain mapping information for those fields. They may contain some utlity methods which are not defined in the interface but are needed inside the getter and setters for processing data.

The entities are **Presentation**, **Attendee** and **Presenter**. **Attendee** extends from the **Participant** model, and **Presenter** from **Attendee**. Now to differentiate I'm using Doctrine's *single table inheritance type* with a discriminator column called **is_presenter** which is mapped at **Attendee** entity.

Basically, a Presenter is able to create a Presentation which thereafter is joined by Attendees.

My question is, should isPresenter have been defined in **ParticipantInterface**? Is the way I've done it worse or fine? If I had left it in the interface, I couldn't use it as a discriminator anyway, but from a logical point of view should it have been in the interface or maybe in another called **PresenterParticipantInterface**?

Comment: This seems like the classic anti-pattern of designing an object hierarchy around the real world objects you're modelling rather than *the operations you want to perform on that model* (e.g. create presentation, join audience, etc). For instance, why do you need/want separate Presenter and Attendee classes? And how do you deal with Presenters who attend other people's presentations?

Comment: @Ixrec: You're damn right, I didn't think about presenters attending other's presentations. So what do you suggest, keeping a single Participant entity and keeping a track of who presents with an isPresenter field? And ultimately, that should be part of the interface as well?

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind is you may be better off with a `Presentation` class which has `presenter` and `attendees` fields of type `PersonID` and list thereof. But this is merely one symptom of the fundamental issue I wanted to point out; namely that you appear to be thinking about types of objects *before* thinking about what you want them to *do*. Issues like this always crop up when you do that.

Comment: @Ixrec: Classroom is kinda the Presentation class you're describing. It can contain 1 presenter and multiple attendess. I already know what I want to do with these objects. Presenters can create classrooms (presentations) in which attendes can join. There is more to it but nothing crucial that changes the fundamental architecture.

Comment: Ah, I see. The name made me assume it represented actual physical rooms, rather than the more abstract idea of a presentation. Though again, this shows how important it is to write down what all these interfaces/classes are meant to do, rather than simply state their names.

Comment: Sorry, my fault about that, I will revise the original post, and probably end up using Presentation instead of Classroom for the name. But I wanted to clarify what is best design, using a singe Participant object to relate to the Presentation and define who is the Presenter based on a property it contains, or separating Presenter and Attendees in different objects. The latter one would produce problems if I wanted to treat Presenters as Attendees tomorrow I guess.

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea what Doctrine is, but from what you are describing looks like ORM.

Regardless, I will speak from SOLID and software design perspective.

I would apply ISP(Interface Segregation Principle from SOLIDs) and have a number interfaces: IAttendee, IParticipant and IPresenter with their own respective methods.

So you could have variations of objects that conform to specifi set of interfaces:

```
public class Attendee extends Participant implements IAttendee { }
public class Presenter extends Attendee implements IPresenter {}
public class Auditor extends Attendee implmenets IAuditor {}
```

**Use interfaces to your advantage, don't just meaninglessly create them because you were told to do so. Mix and match them :)**

Comment: Is it meaningless to create an interface? afaik, an interface describes a contract and the public API. Abstract classes might be meaningless sometimes but I don't see why not creating interfaces. Decoupling is another reason.

Comment: @GlendGjermeni I didn't say it's meaningless to create an interface, but to create one meaninglessly certainly is :)